# how can get value after addition if user left some textbox blank

Tags: c#

I am using following code:

```
textbox5.text =  (Double.Parse(TextBox1.text) 
                + Double.Parse(TextBox2.text) 
                + Double.Parse(TextBox3.text) 
                + Double.Parse(TextBox4.text)).ToString();
```

The problem is if I left any textbox blank then it shows an exception.

Sometimes I want to use only 2 textboxes. Sometimes I want to use only 3 Textboxes and so on

Comment: When exactly are those _some times_ ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) to avoid exceptions for these situations:

```
double val = 0.0;
double temp = 0.0;

if(Double.TryParse(TextBox1.text, out temp))
    val += temp;

//....

textbox5.text = val.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double d1, d2, d3, d4;
    txt5.Text = ((double.TryParse(txt1.Text, out d1) ? d1 : 0) +
    (double.TryParse(txt2.Text, out d2) ? d2 : 0) +
    (double.TryParse(txt3.Text, out d3) ? d3 : 0) +
    (double.TryParse(txt4.Text, out d4) ? d4 : 0)).ToString();
```

easy and short. And will return 0 in the case you provide no value.

Answer (score 0):

Break the Double.Parse() calls apart in their own try/catch blocks, saving the results of each.  For each Parse() call, if it's successful, include that value in the total, and put the total in your final textbox.

Edit: Here's the code:

```
        double value1, value2, value3, value4;
        try
        {
            value1 = Double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            value1 = 0;
        }
        try
        {
            value2 = Double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            value2 = 0;
        }
        [...]
        double total = value1 + value2 + value3 + value4;
        textBox5.Text = total.ToString();
```

While the above is pretty easy to understand, but I'd use Necrolis's solution, as it's more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

```
double TryAddDoubleValue(TextBox textbox, int accumulator) {
  double value;
  if(double.TryParse(textbox.Text, out value)) {
    accumulator += value;
  }
  return accumulator;
}

double result = 0;
result = TryAddDoubleValue(TextBox1, result);
result = TryAddDoubleValue(TextBox2, result);
result = TryAddDoubleValue(TextBox3, result);
result = TryAddDoubleValue(TextBox4, result);

textbox5.Text = result.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Extension method.

```
public static class DoubleExtensions
{
    public static double ParseDouble (this string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(value))
            return 0.0;

        return Double.Parse(value);
    }
}
```

Your code will then become

```
textbox5.text = (TextBox1.text.ParseDouble() + 
            TextBox2.text.ParseDouble() +
            TextBox3.text.ParseDouble() +
            TextBox4.text.ParseDouble() ).ToString();
```